# Optimize multiple row count

Tags: mysql, join, count

There are two tables: `question` and `answer`. In `answer` I hold `user_id` and `question_id`. I want to count how many times each choice is selected.

Below is a working query, but instead of joining the same table 4 times, what is a faster way i.e. joining the answer table only once.

```
SELECT question.question_id,
    question.correct_choice,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) as num_of_a,
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id) as num_of_b,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.user_id) as num_of_c,
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.user_id) as num_of_d
FROM answer a,
    answer b, 
    answer c, 
    answer d,
    question 
WHERE a.question_id = question.question_id 
    AND b.question_id = question.question_id
    AND c.question_id = question.question_id 
    AND d.question_id = question.question_id 
    AND a.choice = 'A' 
    AND b.choice = 'B'
    AND c.choice = 'C' 
    AND d.choice = 'D'  
GROUP BY question.question_id 
ORDER BY question.question_id asc;
```

returns

```
273, D, 5, 2, 8, 39
274, C, 2, 14, 50, 2
277, C, 3, 5, 41, 17
278, C, 16, 9, 34, 9
279, C, 8, 30, 24, 12
280, B, 17, 21, 20, 3
284, C, 2, 3, 19, 1
286, A, 16, 3, 2, 2
287, D, 1, 2, 1, 18
289, B, 3, 18, 2, 2
290, D, 6, 9, 8, 6
```

Comment: can you give information on the structure of your tables?

Comment: What's wrong with the way it is now?  With proper indexes, this should be a fairly fast query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution only does a single join... additionally, I converted your implicit joins to explicit, and rounded out your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    q.question_id,
    q.correct_choice,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.choice = 'A' THEN a.user_id END) as num_of_a,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.choice = 'B' THEN a.user_id END) as num_of_b,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.choice = 'C' THEN a.user_id END) as num_of_c,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.choice = 'D' THEN a.user_id END) as num_of_d
FROM 
    answer a
    JOIN question q ON a.question_id = q.question_id
GROUP BY q.question_id, q.correct_choice
ORDER BY q.question_id asc;
```

This works because when the `CASE` statement doesn't evaluate to true, it returns `NULL`, which won't be included in the `COUNT DISTINCT` of user Ids.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a SELECT... UNION SELECT style if you are concerned about performance.

Although I would agree with @benjam that you should EXPLAIN the results to see what optimizer is saying, since you do not have a dependent queries.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have indexes on `question.question_id`, and on `answer.question_id`, `answer.choice`, and `answer.user_id` and your query should be just as fast as any other that does not join answer for each choice.  Then use the following query:

```
SELECT `question`.`question_id`,
    `question`.`correct_choice`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `a`.`user_id`) as `num_of_a`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `b`.`user_id`) as `num_of_b`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `c`.`user_id`) as `num_of_c`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `d`.`user_id`) as `num_of_d`
FROM `question`
    LEFT JOIN `answer` AS `a`
        USING(`a`.`question_id` = `question`.`question_id`
            AND `a`.`choice` = 'A'),
    LEFT JOIN `answer` AS `b`
        USING(`b`.`question_id` = `question`.`question_id`
            AND `b`.`choice` = 'B'),
    LEFT JOIN `answer` AS `c`
        USING(`c`.`question_id` = `question`.`question_id`
            AND `c`.`choice` = 'C'),
    LEFT JOIN `answer` AS `d`
        USING(`d`.`question_id` = `question`.`question_id`
            AND `d`.`choice` = 'D')
GROUP BY `question`.`question_id` ;
```

The ORDER BY clause is not needed and implied from the GROUP BY clause.